# How do I configure syntastic to use Python3 in Ubuntu?

Tags: filetype-python, plugin-syntastic, linux-ubuntu

The following code shows `invalid syntax`. I assume syntastic is looking at Python2 for syntax-checking. I need it to look at Python3 instead.

```
def x():
  x = 42
  def y():
    nonlocal x
    x = 8
    return x
  return y

print( x()() )
```

`nonlocal` is the method of telling Python3 that you do not want to shadow `x`. It's a great and powerful feature that let's me quick and easily obscure code, and one of the many benefits of lacking `my`, `let`, `dim`, and the like on variable declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Ubuntu, I couldn't figure out what was calling python or to change the default environment for all instances of syntastic. That would have been desirable.

Instead what I did was install `flake8`,

```
pip3 install flake8
```

Then you can easily configure this to work by adding the following line to your `~/.vimrc`

```
let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['flake8']
```

Beware though this has a lot of stuff that isn't just syntax checking, including a style-guide. I'm not sure why this just be as changing the default in a vim conf, but this seems to work.

Comment: ... which doesn't work, because there is no __syntastic checker__ named `python3`.  Believe it or not, the solution is described in the [FAQ](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#faqpython).

Comment: @lcd047 good catch, it wasn't working. the error went away but it wasn't catching subsequent errors I moved to use flake8 which is certainly working (and loud af)